# Is it possible to call external web APIs from Slack?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to pull some metrics daily posted in my slack channel. these metrics are located in my personal server, and to pull them via rest API a basic authentication is also required.

Does slack support this?in other words can slack do external api call in such way?
and if yes how?

Comment: You can use Slack's Events API -> https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to create a custom application(bot).

 You can implement your custom business logic and then use slack APIs to post generated data to Slack Client.

https://slack.com/intl/en-in/help/articles/115005265703-Create-a-bot-for-your-workspace